# Change bins on y-axis with seaborn

Tags: python, histogram, seaborn

I try to work out some way to plot data as a histogram. Now I realized that the numbers on the y-axis don't represent the actual counts of data points in my file. Is there a way I can change that?

My code looks like this

```
sns.set_style("white")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.xlabel('a', fontsize=18) 
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=18)

plt.title ('Title of Graph', fontsize=22)



sns.distplot(st,bins='fd', kde=False, fit_kws={"color":"red"}, fit=sp.stats.norm, hist_kws={"rwidth":0.75, 'range':(0,1), 'edgecolor':'black', 'alpha':1.0}, axlabel='Ratio ')
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Not sure why you use a distplot if you want a histogram. `pyplot.hist` gives you a histogram.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually havent't tried that. But can I combine it with the looks of seaborn graphs? That's the prime reason I try to make it work with seaborn

Comment: OK, so with a little testing I figured out my mistake. The fit=sp.stats.norm does normalize my values. If I remove it, my graphs look like I expect them to.